# Unable to detect adb version, adb output: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu OS which has below version

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:precise
```

I updated android studio API support 23 to 24 but after updating android studio when I the run project it always gives me following error :

```
Unable to detect adb version, adb output: android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: 3: android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string.
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Thank you.